# How to update value within firestore query using dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is a query that returns some data from the firestore database.
After getting the docs, I want to update a specific key(distance_away) value before returning the final List

```
return db
            .collection(Global.marketplaceRef)
            .where("point.geohash", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: range.lower)
            .where("point.geohash", isLessThanOrEqualTo: range.upper)
            .limit(20)
            .snapshots()
            .map((list)  => (list.docs
          
             .map((e)  {
              // Update value here before returning doc. 
              // This doesn't seem to do that
              return (e.data().update('distance_away', (value) => 100.toString())).toList();
              })
            ).toList()
          );
```

I want to alter the distance_away value of each doc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the reference object not .data() try something like this

```
 .map((list)  => (list.docs
      
         .map((e)  {
          return (e.reference.update({'distance_away': ['100']}
        ).toList()
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, but the query never seems to end and it returns a DocumentReference not matching DocumentSnapshot type erro.

Comment: of course since .update function is void you can't use .map() you should first fetch the documents and after that update the documents by using .forEach()